# Kubernetes, can one VPA manage multiple Cronjobs?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

Say I have this VPA config file:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: vpa-reco
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "batch/v1beta1"
    kind: CronJob
    name: test-autoscaling-1
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"
```

How can I make my VPA target CronJob `test-autoscaling-2` also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't reference multiple objects in a single `VPA` object.

If you tried like below (to have 2 `CronJobs` in a single `VPA`):

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: vpa-reco
spec:
  targetRef:
  - apiVersion: "batch/v1beta1"
    kind: CronJob
    name: test-autoscaling-1
  - apiVersion: "batch/v1beta1"
    kind: CronJob
    name: test-autoscaling-2
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"
```

You should got the error (part of it) similar to the one below:

```sh
denied the request: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field VerticalPodAutoscalerSpec.targetRef of type v1.CrossVersionObjectReference
```

To have the `VPA` configured for: `test-autoscaling-1` and `test-autoscaling-2` **you would need to create 2 separate `VPA` objects** like: `vpa-reco-1` and `vpa-reco-2`.

---

Talking from the perspective of a `VPA` with `CronJob`, support for it was added in the version `0.7.0`. More can be found in this specific release note:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Autoscaler: Releases: Tag: Vertical pod autoscaler 0.7.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/releases/tag/vertical-pod-autoscaler-0.7.0)*

Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler)*